# iPad 3 with USB hard drive

Tags: ipad, usb

is it possible to use a USB hard drive with the iPad 3? Do I need to download an app to use it (assuming I have the camera connection kit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with the [iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A/ipad-camera-connection-kit), but in a very limited manner. You can import photos or videos on an external drive to the Photos app, if you set up the file structure to emulate a USB-connected camera - I believe you need a folder in the root directory named `DCIM` with the photo and video files within named `DCIM_1234.jpg` (or `.mp4`, etc. as appropriate).

You may find this article useful: [CNet: Secrets of the iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57401068-285/secrets-of-the-ipad-camera-connection-kit/)

Comment: is this compatible with the iPad3? http://tinyurl.com/8sgycw8

Comment: Yes, the one model is compatible with all three generations of iPads.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I have an older iPad , it's the iPad 3. 
I have a WHITE IPAD 1/2/3 USB ADAPTOR CONNECTION PORT KIT - Female end USB, bought from eBay.
Into this I can plug in any USB device.
My Apple 2002 White pro keyboard does NOT WORK due to it requiring too much power.
However, my cheap as chips TRUST ( WINDOWS ) Keyboard, bought from Morrisons works... The upshot is you will only be able to get a low power USB keyboard to work, low current requirement...  I have typed this out on my KB with no silly error messages.... Hope this helps !